# How to force cdecl calling convention for functions declared in specific header file

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Hi
My VC2008 project uses the stdcall calling conventions. I have an external library that I am using which has been built with cdecl naming convention, however they didn't mention the calling convention in the function declaration of the functions.

I would like to know if VC has some kind of #pragma or other keyword that would force specific calling convention for the entire header file

kinda like the extern "C" trick but for calling conventions:

```
extern "C" 
{
#include <file1.h>
#include <file2.h> 
}
```

Anyone knows of such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify calling convention by:

- Do nothing and you get the default of cdecl.
- Specify `__cdecl` explicitly (or perhaps through a macro).
- Elect to use cdecl throughout a translation unit by compiling with /Gd.

There's no pragma or anything similiar to control calling convention.

Comment: The first two are the obvious ones and the ones I am trying to avoid. God knows how many of function definitions I will have to change. Just to correct you, the default is not cdecl, it is whatever is set in project Settings (which in my case is set to stdcall).

Comment: I'm talking about the compiler default. The IDE overrides that default if you change the default project settings (which are also cdecl).

Comment: I am still looking for modification-less solution. Perhaps Visual Studio specific pragma or anything like that.

Comment: @Kostya: No, the standard libraries that come with the compiler use a __cdecl per function in their headers.

Comment: @Kostya There's no pragma to control calling convention.

Comment: Seeing as there is no other way, I had the lib compiled as stdcall and that solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have exactly same problem - and the bad thing is that the cause is MS BTLE library which I cannot recompile of course.